# Difference between same repetition on each set and limit repetition on each set

Tags: exercise, exercise-technique, home-exercise, sets

What is the benefit difference between doing a move 20x3 and getting exhausted at the end and doing the same move up to the limit each set (28,20,13)

I am currently waiting 1min between each set and then trying to go up to limit again.

I am working at home with body weight and dumbells.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Can you please elaborate ?

Answer (score 1):

Broadly speaking, two things: one, there may be a difference in total volume (60 reps at that weight versus 61 reps at that weight; in this case it's negligible but in other cases it can be substantial), two, you get the benefits and drawbacks of going to failure when you go to failure and not when you don't.

Going to failure--that is, doing reps until you just cannot physically do one more--is extremely stressful. This can be good: you know you reached your limit (for that particular moment), you stimulate muscle growth, you train to push through fatigue. It can also be bad: the same stress that stimulates muscle growth can cause joint pain or inflammation, and pushing past fatigue leads to diminishing quality of form and therefore risks injury.